# Python PIP giving error - "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ip_address'"

Tags: python, pip

I am actually having a problem with installing any modules using PIP. Whenever I run PIP like

> pip install module_name

OR

> sudo pip install module-name

" then it'll show an error like this:-

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 294, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 461, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 250, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 486, in find_requirement
    all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 425, in _find_all_versions
    if self._validate_secure_origin(logger, link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 301, in _validate_secure_origin
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ip_address'
```

Importantly:-

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ip_address
```

Reinstalling does nothing

Comment: can you specify which module give you this error ?
and can you post that whole line you are using to install a module

Comment: Anything actually @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi. I tried opencv.

Comment: did you do that like this `pip install opencv-contrib-python` or like this `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: Are you getting this error for other modules too?

Comment: Do one thing, open python 2.7 and type: `import ipaddress` and then `ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')`, please notify what is the outcome?

Comment: @UbdusSamad it says "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ip_address'"

Comment: Are you good with copying and pasting protected files through terminal in ubntu?

Comment: @UbdusSamad - Yeah I am good at that!

Comment: Then go to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` , down below you'll see a python file named **ipaddress.py** , make a safe copy of it (ofcourse you'll need root acess to all of this). Now download [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q9TlKFTL0q-S1Rt16-bru1VnBOMHDxLX/view?usp=sharing) and replace you previous one with the newly downloaded one and try pip again. If everything seems to crash just replace your original file back.

Comment: @UbdusSamad I've tried everything you told and it says "ipaddress.AddressValueError: '192.168.0.1' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Did you pass in a bytes (str in Python 2) instead of a unicode object?"

Comment: Good , It means that's it's now recognizing `ipaddress.ip_address()`. Now run PIP again .

Comment: Is it working? I man PIP??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the following commands:

```
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
...
Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip

$ sudo pip uninstall requests
...
  Successfully uninstalled requests-1.1.0

$ sudo pip install requests
...
Successfully installed requests-2.12.4

$ pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```